# sigma fields measures

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying basics measure theory, and am stuck with the following problem:

> Let Ω = {(i, j) : i, j ∈ {1, . . . , 6}}, F = P(Ω) and define the
> random variables $X_1$(i, j) = i and $X_2$(i, j) = j.
>
> Is X1 + X2 measurable with respect to either σ($X_1$) or σ($X_2$)?

The given answer to this is no because :

> For example, take B = {12}. Then
> {ω ∈ Ω : $X_1$(ω) + $X_2$(ω) ∈ B} = {(i, j) ∈ Ω : $X_2$(i, j) + $X_2$(i, j) = 12}
> = {(i, j) ∈ Ω : i + j = 12} = {(6, 6)},
> which is in neither of the two sigma fields σ($X_1$), σ($X_2$).

The part that troubles me is that from what I understood, the σ($X_1$) is the list of all unions of the atoms [{(i,1),(i,2)...(i,6)} for i in range (1-6 included)] which does include (6,6) in one of it's atoms.

Where is my confusion ?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_1(i,j)=k$ is same $i=k$ and $j$ **arbitrary**. This means $\sigma (X_1)$ consists of sets of the form $A \times \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with $A \subseteq \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. So $\{(6,6)\}$ is not in $\sigma (X_1)$